# Maven execute only one plugin among two based on a property

Tags: pom.xml, maven-plugin

I use two maven plugins among which I want to execute only one depending upon property passed as argument.

```
<properties>
  <global>false</global>
</properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>..</groupId>
      <artifactId>plugin1-runs-globally</artifactId>
      <version>..</version>
      <configuration>
        <skip>!${global}</skip>
      </configuration>
      <executions>..</executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>..</groupId>
      <artifactId>plugin2-runs-locally</artifactId>
      <version>..</version>
      <configuration>
        <skip>${global}</skip>
      </configuration>
      <executions>..</executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

> mvn clean install -Dglobal=true

should run only plugin1 and not plugin2 whereas

> mvn clean install

should run only plugin2 and not plugin1.

But !$(global) seems symantically wrong. Can someone help me with a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't use any boolean type properties, but I would advise you to use profiles for this.

What you can do is create two profiles:

`<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>non-global</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>..</groupId>
          <artifactId>plugin1-runs-locally</artifactId>
          <version>..</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>`

This profile is used when nothing is specified (so always).

For the global plugin, you can have a profile which is either activated by a maven profile id. You can also use a property to active a profile if you like. See for instance the following configuration.

`<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>global</id>
    <!-- optional -->
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>global</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <!-- optional -->
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>..</groupId>
          <artifactId>plugin2-runs-locally</artifactId>
          <version>..</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>`

Now when you want to execute the plugin related to the global profile all you need to do is:

> mvn clean install -Pglobal

Or when using a property:

> mvn clean install -Dglobal

And if you want the non-global plugin to execute, you can use

> mvn clean install

See the maven profile documentation for more background information.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: So do you mean at a time only one profile will work? Also, I have a third plugin which needs to execute for both profiles. So, do I need to include in both profiles separately?

Comment: You can use both profiles at the same time. You can use a comma-separated list of profiles while running your maven command.  If you have a plugin which needs to execute in both profiles you can just put it in the normal build section (so not within one of the profiles). If you have specific requirements for that same plugin per profile you will need to define the plugin in both profiles.